Send a POST request from a Windows 10 toast notification through PowerShell
I was making a simple Toast notification with a text box and a button that would send a POST request with the TextBox data. Something like this.

When I press "Reply" I wanted to send a POST notification with the text box with it's id textBox. Now the code I did, the notification did work, however, when I typed something and pressed "Reply", that data isnt sending.
here's the code.
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null

$app = '{UUID}\powershell.exe'


$template = @"
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>Hello World</text>
            <text>This is a simple toast message</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
    <actions>
        <input id="textBox" type="text" placeHolderContent="Type a reply" arguments="textBoxTest" />
        <action activationType="foreground" content="Reply" arguments="reply" />
    </actions>
</toast>
"@

$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($template)
$toast = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::new($xml)

$toast.add_Activated({
    param($sender, $e)
    $reply = $e.UserInput['textBox']
    
    # Send POST request
    $uri = "https://your-api-endpoint.com"
    $body = @{
        id = $reply
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
})

[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier("$app").Show($toast)

is there anything missing or something I can replace?

What you are doing does not make any sense.  You have a client and a server which are two different processes.  So you are sending a message from the client to the server and then expect the message to appear in a textbox on the client.

My guess is that the problem is that the event handler is called from a different thread, and in the absence of a PowerShell runspace being associated with that thread the PowerShell code cannot execute. Perhaps the BurntToast PowerShell module offers a solution.
